# API requests return 302 (instead of 200) when splitting to multiple 'it'?

Tags: cypress

I have one test that I created and I split it into 4 different `it`s.
The first one is responsible for visiting the website, logging in, etc. and the other ones are responsible for testing different logic.

All tests are dependent on each other, although they are split into 4 `it`s.

I noticed that this way, API calls made in the last `it`s return 302 status code instead of 200 - which doesn't happen if I put all the test logic under the same `it`.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: _"All tests are dependant on each other, although they are split into 4 `it`s"_ - don't do that. Various state is cleared between tests, which should be independent.

Comment: This might help [Cypress not properly intercepting leaflet map tile calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620242/cypress-not-properly-intercepting-leaflet-map-tile-calls/71624371#71624371) if your intercept is failing because of caching.